# Lua script - find digits in a string

Tags: lua, lua-patterns, asa

I have a Cisco ASA 8.4 VPN Concentrator.  I am trying to use Lua to extract digits from a certificate string coming in and use them in a LDAP lookup with AD for authorization.  I found a string that works...sometimes.

The string comes in with the format:

```
LAST_NAME.FIRST_NAME.MIDDLE_NAME.1234567890
```

My LDAP only wants to see the digits and @domainname.  The script I am currently us is: `return string.gsub(cert.subject.cn, "^(%w+)%.(%w+)%.(%w+)%.(%w+)$", "%4@domain")`

This script works fine in most cases (80-90% of the time).  When it doesn't work is when people have no middle name, 4 names instead of 3, etc.

My question is how can I get it to output only the 10 digits, regardless of what comes before it.  Seems too easy with a return string.match, but so far I can't get it to work.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the pattern `.*(%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d)$`:

```
local str = 'LAST_NAME.FIRST_NAME.MIDDLE_NAME.1234567890'
print(str:match('.*(' .. ('%d'):rep(10) .. ')$'))
```

or `.*(%d+)$` if the number of digits is always 10.

If the 10 digits is always the last 10 characters, this works:

```
print(str:sub(-10, -1))
```

Comment: may be just `str:match("(%d+)$")`?